# Buffering of expensive functions on hard drive

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are functions in my program that take relatively long to compute and at the same time are only created in a specific number of ways. Is there an implementation in Python (library, maybe even a decorator implementation, etc.) where the function is executed only if there is no buffer file available on the hard drive? Something like:

```
def main():
    sub_function(param1, param2)


def sub_function(param1, param2):
    if buffer_file_with_exact_same_arguments_exists_on_hd(param1, param2):
        return buffered_result
    ... time-consuming main function body ...
    save_to_hd(param1, param2)
    return result
```

I wrote something like that myself, but noticed that there might be special cases that might cause errors. Seeing that other people might have the same problem, I was wondering whether anybody knows a good library or other solution. Thank you very much!

Edit: A solution was suggested where decorators are used, but these work only in RAM and do not buffer to the hard drive. An implementation that works with hard drive buffering would be much preferred.

Comment: You might be looking for [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) (part of the standard library and can be used as a decorator).

Comment: @jakub I think `functools.cache` onyl caches to RAM, so one would have to implement on-disk caching yourself in a similar way.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa - you are correct. The [implementation of the infinite cache](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d7a1a815d9dbb9ea0bf791163cc135e9cff68add/Lib/functools.py#L550-L561) stores results in a python `dict`.

Comment: That already helps a lot. Do you know how I can best (and safely) access the dict (including writing upon starting up the system)?